# How to add thumbnail to list items?

Tags: android

My code reads a .txt file which contains strings and displays them in my listview. But how do I read another .txt file which will contain links to images and then load those images as thumbnail to each list item?

```
listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    try {
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/my_market_apps_list.txt";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(filePath), "Cp1252"), 100);
        String line;
        final ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="
                                + lines.get(position))));
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter by default is only able to show text, so first you'll gonna need to create a more complex view to show images as well. For that, you can either extend ArrayAdapter and overwrite its [getView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method to provide your own view, or just create a custom adapter based on [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) instead.

Then, you'll need a data structure that holds both your strings and the image urls. You'll have to create a custom class for that, and use that in your ArrayAdapter instead of strings. How you actually populate those classes with your data depends on how your data is structured, but you'll need some way to create a mapping between your string and image data.

Lastly, to actually load those image urls into ImageViews, you'll need some HTTP code. ImageViews can't load remote images themselves. Easiest way would probably be to use a library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso).